# WSO2 EI/ESB - Calling multiple endpoints in sequence to generate a custom object

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

What I'm trying to achieve:

Using an Enterprise Integrator API, I want to combine the data from two data service endpoints (call it ORDERS and METADATAS) into a custom object like so:

```
[
  {
     Order: {},
     Metadata: {}
  }, ...
]
```

The API takes in a single parameter at the moment, `USER_ID`.
When I run the `<call>` mediator in blocking mode, I get the following problem:

`Current Params: {USER_ID={1,1}, ID=test}`

or

`Current Params: {USER_ID={test,1}}`

When in non-blocking mode, the first call works successfully and the second call can't proceed. It seems it can't access the `USER_ID` parameter from the URL, nor from the stored property. I thought properties were supposed to persist values?

It should be noted that the values in the logs are 100% accurate (USER_ID property is showing correct value).

`INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  _TEST = 1, _TEST2 = 1, _TEST3 = 1`

Here's what I've got thus far for the inSequence:

```xml
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test?USER_ID={USER_ID}">
    <inSequence>
        <property expression="get-property('query.param.USER_ID')" name="USER_ID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <property expression="$url:USER_ID" name="uri.var.USER_ID" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
        <call blocking="true">
            <endpoint>
                <http method="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://localhost:8243/services/ORDERS_DataService/user/{query.param.USER_ID}"/>
            </endpoint>
        </call>
        <log level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('USER_ID')" name="_TEST"/>
            <property expression="get-property('query.param.USER_ID')" name="_TEST2"/>
            <property expression="get-property('uri.var.USER_ID')" name="_TEST3"/>
        </log>
        <enrich>
            <source clone="false" type="body"/>
            <target property="_ORDERS" type="property"/>
        </enrich>
        <filter regex="200" source="get-property('axis2', 'HTTP_SC')">
            <then>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="switchlog" value="Case: first call successful"/>
                </log>
                <call blocking="true">
                    <endpoint>
                        <http method="get" statistics="enable" trace="enable" uri-template="https://localhost:8243/services/ORDERS_DataService/metadata/user/{query.param.USER_ID}"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </call>
                <enrich>
                    <source clone="false" type="body"/>
                    <target property="_METADATAS" type="property"/>
                </enrich>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property expression="get-property('_METADATAS')" name="_METADATAS"/>
                </log>
            </then>
            <else/>
        </filter>
    </inSequence>
</resource>
```

What have I tried?

Using `{USER_ID}`, `{uri.var.USER_ID}`, `{$url:USER_ID}`, and `{query.param.USER_ID}` in both of the uri-templates for the `<call>`s.

Tried non-blocking and blocking mode, getting different results.

My problem is just (for now) with the calling of both sequences and assigning to properties.

I planned to bring them all together with an iterate, and something like the below to map the properties to each of the items in the array I'm looking for:

```xml
<!-- Assuming iterate provides _ORDER and _METADATA whilst looping -->
<format>
{
    "Order":"$1",
    "Metadata":"$2"
}
</format>
<args>
    <arg expression="get-property('_ORDER')"/>
    <arg expression="get-property('_METADATA')"/>
</args>
```

And if that doesn't work I was going to evaluate an XSLT transform on the two items, but I haven't thought that far ahead yet, stuck on the two calls not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the answer to the issue. Found this curious line buried in the documentation [1]:

```xml
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

Adding it just after grabbing the query parameter works! It does exactly what it says, apparently a Postfix is applied by default. Now to look for a global way to turn that off automatically!

**References:**

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI650/Configuring+Specific+Use+Cases